# What version of smarty uses syntax like [-php-] code here [-/php-]?

Tags: smarty

I have seen some codes used in smarty like [-php-] [-/php-]. I wonder what version of smarty used these kind of syntax. I have seen some other syntax also like {php} {/php}.

Answer (score 0):

Version 2 and up (not sure about previous versions) of Smarty allows you to change the delimiters used, so i.e. you can use {tag}, {{tag}}, [-tag-], [[tag]], etc... you can even use different types of opening and closing delimiters (i.e. "{tag]]")